# How to read data from JQuery getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am struggling with getJSON. I have a simple StockWatcher application which returns the data in JSON format

```
http://localhost:8080/StockWatcherServer/stockwatcher/stockPrices?q=ABC+DEF+PQR
```

Output:

```
({
    "stocks": [{
        "symbol": "ABC",
        "price": 80.11611442288577,
        "change": 1.4332410131550721
    }, {
        "symbol": "DEF",
        "price": 89.47611015580729,
        "change": -1.469336678470048
    }, {
        "symbol": "PQR",
        "price": 99.60017237722221,
        "change": -1.3303545392913447
    }]
})
```

When I use a simple Javascript function to read this, I get a Error (.error, .complete and .second complete)

I have used Firebug to debug this, and I can see that I can retrieve the object but I see a XML error

> XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: moz-nullprincipal:{0daef08f-94bc-4bea-879f-6456e8175e38} Line Number 1, Column 1:

```
({"stocks": [ ^
```

Here is the Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var url='http://localhost:8080/StockWatcherServer/stockwatcher/stockPrices?q=';
var query;
    $('button').click(function(){
        query=$("#query").val();
        // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
        // and remember the jqxhr object for this request    
        var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(obj,function(i,item){
                $("#results").append('Title:'+item.symbol+' ==  Price:'+item.price+'</p>');
            });
        })
        .success(function(data) { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function(data) { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function(data) { alert("complete"); });
        // perform other work here ...

        // Set another completion function for the request above
        jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });       
    });
});
</script>
```

I have experimented with various options calling parseJSON and without parseJSON,
but seems it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it really come back from the server with the () around it (as in your example ({"stocks": [ { ... ]}) )? Because I pasted everything inside the parenthesis ({"stocks": [ { ... ]}) into the online tool http://json.parser.online.fr/ and it correctly translated it into an object, just like parseJSON would. P.S. assuming that there are parenthesis there causing a problem, you won't need parseJSON because getJSON() will take care of that.

Comment: @JohnMunsch: I was thinking the same thing.  The `()` are causing this error, lose 'em.

Comment: Is your page also running on `http://localhost:8080`?  If not, you need JSONP instead of JSON.  Also, `$.getJSON` parses it for you, you don't need `$.parseJSON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something more like this... Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url='http://localhost:8080/StockWatcherServer/stockwatcher/stockPrices?q=';
var query;
    $('button').click(function(){
        query=$("#query").val();

        // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
        // and remember the jqxhr object for this request    
        $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.stocks,function(i,item){
                $("#results").append('Title:'+item.symbol+' ==  Price:'+item.price+'</p>');
            });
        },
        error: function(data) { alert("error"); },
        });

        // perform other work here ...
    });
});
```

Comment: I meant to make it .ajax and then I got busy.

Comment: Ok, I did two things as you both suggested. 

Firstly, I removed the starting "(" and ending ")" in the JSON data/ 

Secondly I changed the call from .getJSON to .ajax, one minor change was I had to reference the stocks in the data. 
$.each(data.stocks,function(i,item......
My question : What is the purpose of .getJSON, I thought it was a wrapper around .ajax which did GET

Answer (score 0):

If you use "(" and ")" in your original JSON, try this :

```
{
    "stocks": [
        {
            "symbol": "ABC",
            "price": 80.11611442288577,
            "change": 1.4332410131550721
        },
        {
            "symbol": "DEF",
            "price": 89.47611015580729,
            "change": -1.469336678470048
        },
        {
            "symbol": "PQR",
            "price": 99.60017237722221,
            "change": -1.3303545392913447
        }
    ]
}
```