# jquery getJSON() function (get whole json object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

Because I work currently with an API returning JSON code I would need to get the whole JSON code returned by API and insert this code line by line (well formatted, if possible in an easy way) into a `<pre>` element.

My code I use at the moment:

```
$.getJSON(url + "api/get", function( data ) {

$.each(data, function(i, field){
  $("#result").append(field);
  console.log(field);
  }); 
});
```

Using the console output I get:

```
Object {message: "api key invalid"}
```

This seems to be strange, because when using postman to debug I get:

```
{"errors":{"message":"api key invalid"}}
```

How to get the response postman gets and how to insert this into my pre element, because at the moment this doesn't work too.

Comment: Why not skip the JSON parsing and just `$.get()` the content as raw text?

Comment: `console.log(data)` to see how the object looks then access the properties as needed. This might help ► http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709241/how-to-read-data-from-jquery-getjson

Comment: @FrançoisWahl i already tried this too, it returns: [https://puu.sh/t9RTn/be6778344d.png](this). I just need to get the whole JSON object, so I can place this into a `<pre>` textbox, to show my users the whole reply from the API.

Comment: `$("#result").append(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));`

Comment: @FelixKling that would work of course but it'd lose any newline formatting that the real API response supplies. If the OP just wants the text I don't see why anything needs to treat it as JSON anyway.

Comment: @wichtel There is a function JSON.stringify() that will take a JSON object that has been through JSON.parse(), or a plain JS object, and output a string. You want to take the response from your $.getjson() and use stringify adding the result to your display element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify for details of stringify - is a handy tool.

Comment: @Pointy Your assumption that there is white space and that it is desired may not be true. However the OP does want ` to show my users the whole reply from the API` so on that basis I concur that plain text would best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$.each()` loop is looping over every property in the response, and ignoring the property name.

You just want the whole `data` object, without any loops.

To display the message, check the object's properties.

Comment: How to access them when using `getJSON()`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects